# How to retry transient Avro serialization/deserialisation problems in kafka producers and consumers?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

Because of infrastructure issues, I occasionally see timeouts getting schemas from our avro schema registry.

I don't have a full stack trace, but a typical error message is:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Could not register new Avro schema: Could not retrieve schema for subject 'my-topic-name': connect timed out
```

This locates the issue to an `IOException` in `com.tibco.messaging.kafka.avro.AvroSerializer.getSchemaID`.

I have written a retrying serializer which fixes the issue (and I'll need to do the same for deserialization), but I'd like to know whether there is any configuration I could have done to avoid writing this code.

```
import com.tibco.messaging.kafka.avro.AvroSerializer;
import com.tibco.messaging.schema.registry.SchemaRegistryCache;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import java.util.Map;

public class RetryingAvroSerializer implements Serializer<Object> {
    private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(RetryingAvroSerializer.class);
    private final AvroSerializer avroSerializer = new AvroSerializer();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey) {
        avroSerializer.configure(configs, isKey);
    }

    public void configure(Map<String, ?> configs, boolean isKey, SchemaRegistryCache sharedCache) {
        avroSerializer.configure(configs, isKey, sharedCache);
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, Object data) {
        int retries = 5;
        int delay = 10;
        while (true) {
            try {
                return avroSerializer.serialize(topic, data);
            } catch (org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException e) {
                if (retries == 0) {
                    throw e;
                }
                log.warn("Retrying serialization for {}", topic);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(delay);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
                retries--;
                delay *= 2;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka producers alone, already have `retries` property for the whole request.

So, no, Kafka (or rather, Confluent) serializers have no retry mechanisms, so you will need code such as what you've written if you only want to retry serialization.

Alternatively, I'd recommend tuning your Schema Registry for more high availability (run more instances? Use a load balancer?)

Comment: Thanks, we are also looking at the schema registry -- apparently a later version of the schema registry (1.4?) has better behaviour under load.

Comment: Not sure what version that is referring to. The Confluent Schema Registry is up to versions 7.x now, and I am only familiar with versions as low as 3.x

Comment: Based on TIBCO docs, you can configure the registry with Nginx as a reverse proxy - https://community.tibco.com/s/article/how-configure-tibco-messaging-apache-kafka-schema-repository-nginx

Comment: `tibschemad` was the component which we were recommended to upgrade to 1.4 or later.

Comment: A complication for us is that we have configured an `org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer` which I believe means that Kafka won't retry errors caused be deserialisation problems.

Comment: If you don't commit the offsets, then seek backwards to the previous offset, then yes, it will

Comment: Another contributing factor is that the tibco avro serialisation client library uses a thread local cache -- we have a multi threaded application, so requests are made to `tibschemad` for each thread, where you would hope that one request would suffice...

Comment: As mentioned, I haven't used that. I'm only familiar with the Confluent version. But that uses a concurrent Hashmap... Producers are thread safe, btw, so you wouldn't need multiple threads of those

Comment: Confluent >> Tibco perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

It seems nowadays you can do sth like the following to achieve exactly the same result with only configuration and no custom code (https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/kafka/serdes.html#retrying-deserialization).

Note that you have to first apply the RetryingDeserializer and then if the retries are exhausted the ErrorHandlingDeserializer kicks in and you can have the classic re-consumption policies.

Also I believe that if you are blockingly retry for long enough via the RetryingDeserializer, you will trigger a consumer group rebalance. So you might try to do blocking for 1 minute (or up to the limit that is does not trigger re-balancing) and then do a recover() and throw a custom exception that triggers re-consumption via the ErrorHandlingDeserializer.

```
  @Bean
  public RetryTemplate retryForeverNetworkErrorsTemplate() {
    return RetryTemplate.builder()
        .infiniteRetry()
        .retryOn(IOException.class)
        .traversingCauses()
        .build();
  }


  @Bean
  public ErrorHandlingDeserializer<Object> retryingValueDeserializer(
      RetryTemplate retryForeverNetworkErrorsTemplate, SchemaRegistryClient schemaRegistryClient) {
    return new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(
        new RetryingDeserializer<>(
            new KafkaAvroDeserializer(schemaRegistryClient), retryForeverNetworkErrorsTemplate));
  }

  @Bean
  public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory(
      RetryingDeserializer<String> retryingKeyDeserializer,
      RetryingDeserializer<Object> retryingValueDeserializer) {
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
            consumerConfigs(), retryingKeyDeserializer, retryingValueDeserializer);
  }
```

You could also retry recoverable http errors like 500 ones using the following policy:

```
ExpressionRetryPolicy retryRegistry5xxErrors =
        new ExpressionRetryPolicy(
            "cause instanceof T(io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.rest.exceptions.RestClientException) and cause?.errorCode >= 500");
    retryRegistry5xxErrors.setMaxAttempts(blockingRetries);
```